# Limit of n-th root

Tags: analysis, limits

Can I say that the limes of $\sqrt[n]{(17^n+n^2)}$ is 17 because the right factor below converges against one as n approaches infinity?

$ \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 17*\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{n^2}{17^n})}$

Regards,
Carlster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{n^2}{17^n}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{n^2}{17^n} \right)^{1/n}
$$
Now, it is not true in general that if $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$,
then $(a_n)^{b_n} \to a^b$.
However, this is the case when $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, since for $n$ sufficiently large
$$
\left(\tfrac12\right)^{b_n}< (a_n)^{b_n} < 2^{b_n}
$$
with $\left(\tfrac12\right)^{b_n}, 2^{b_n} \to 1$, so $(a_n)^{b_n} \to 1$ by the squeeze theorem.  Therefore you can say your limit is $1^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to prove that $\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{n^2}{17^n})}$ tends to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity.

This follows because $n^2/17^n$ tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, thus

$$\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{n^2}{17^n}\right)\sim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n}{17^n}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow+\infty]{}0,$$

hence by continuity of $\exp$ you get

$$\sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{n^2}{17^n})}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow+\infty]{}\exp(0)=1.$$